# DJANGO - How to show "Nothing Found for your seach" If no data found

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset, django-filter

I would like to know if there is a way to show a div, or at least "Nothing found" in django when there is no match for the user search.

views.py

```
class TaskSearchView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'task_app/task_search.html'
    model = Task

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        usr = self.request.user
        if query:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) & Q(is_public = True) | 
            Q(title__icontains=query) & Q(author = usr) | Q(title__icontains=query) & Q(responsable = usr)) 
           
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.none()
        return object_list
```

task_search.html

```
 <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Seach Results for: {{ request.GET.q }}</h6>
      </div>
....
 {% for query in object_list %}
      </thead>
        <tbody>
      <tr>
          {% if query.importance == "H" %}
          <th  scope="row" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="HIGH"><i style="color: red" class="fas fa-bookmark"></i></th>
          {% endif %}
          {% if query.importance == "M" %}
          <th scope="row" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Medium"><i style="color: orange" class="fas fa-bookmark"></i></th>
          {% endif %}
.....
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

If the query is empty or there is no result I get this:
[image]

but I would like to show a new form, or a message "nothing found..", is that possible? I tried with:

```
{% if object_list != None %}
show results
{%else%}
show not found, form, div...
{% endif %}
```

But it didn't work

Any advice/answer is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a [**`{% for … %} … {% empty %} … {% endfor %}`** template block [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty):

```
<table>
<thead>
    …
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for query in object_list %}
    <tr>
      …
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
    <tr><td colspan="6">Nothing found</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Between the `{% empty %}` and the `{% endfor %}`, you thus specify what to render in case there are no elements in `object_list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a great solution. Sorry I was not able to make a proper look in the docs! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your code was right but you missed something little.

Today me l tried this one,

```
<table>
<thead>
    …
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for query in object_list %}
    <tr>
      …
    </tr>
  {% empty %}
    <tr><td colspan="6">Nothing found</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

But it returned nothing. Yet in my other page it worked.
Now l replaced your `{% else %}` with **{% empty %}** as below

```
 {% if object_list != None %}
show results
#new.......
{% empty %}
show not found, form, div...
.....
{% endif %}
```

Thanks because it was your idea that solved my too